# Storage::delete not deleting the file. The path is correct and the file permissions are correct

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I do not know why I am not able to delete a file in Laravel with the code:

```
$path = storage_path('app/identification_cards') . '/' . $filename;
Storage::delete($path)
```

The command is executed without errors and it returns true.

What I checked:
- the path is correct. If I use the same exact path in a bash terminal (with the "rm" command) the file is deleted;
- the file does have 777 permissions.

I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: did you checked your $path have the exact path where your file is?

Comment: Before deleting, check if the path is correct: `echo $path`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Storage::delete` will point to `storage\app\` path so no need to add app folder name once again

```
  Storage::delete('identification_cards/'.$filename);
```

Comment: Tried. Got it the error: "permission denied". The file has 777 permissions, so I do not why I get that error.

Comment: you need to give permission for storage folder 755

Comment: thanks @iCoders, the problem what the folder (not the storage, the "identification_card") permissions.

Comment: Storage folder permission 777 weren't working, great point @iCoders!

Answer (score 0):

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File instead of Storage. The chunk of code working on my localhost right now:

```
    $separatorLcl=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;// a '\' on win os, '/' on linux or whatever
    $image = $request->file('userprofile_picture');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    try {
        Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('app'
            .$separatorLcl.'public'.$separatorLcl.'rasmho'.$separatorLcl. $filename ) );
    }catch ( \Exception $e){
        l::k('fayli soxta nashud');
    }
    if($request->hasFile('userprofile_picture')){
        l::k('$user2='.$user->name);//logging

        $photo=$user->photo;
        if(is_null($photo)){
            $user->photo()->create([
                'path'=>storage_path('app'
                    .$separatorLcl.'public'.$separatorLcl.'rasmho'.$separatorLcl. $filename )
            ]);
        }
        else{
            l::k($photo->path);//logging
            try {
                File::delete($photo->path);
            }catch ( \Exception $e){
                l::k('fayli photo nest');
            }
            $photo->path=storage_path('app'
                .$separatorLcl.'public'.$separatorLcl.'rasmho'.$separatorLcl. $filename );
            $photo->save();
        }
```